# setNeedsDisplay not calling drawRect:(CGRect)rect

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, cgrect

I'm trying to follow a guide on how to draw some shapes on screen but at the app launch it works fine but I can't "re-draw" the shapes using `setNeedsDisplay` I've tried a lot of stuff floating around like executing on main thread but it doesn't work.

My App is Made of this:

[image]

My UIView has it's own class, `DrawView`. Here is my code:

**DrawView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NSInteger drawType;

@interface DrawView : UIView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
-(void)drawNow:(NSInteger)type;

@end
```

**DrawView.m**

```
#import "DrawView.h"

@implementation DrawView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *color = [UIColor orangeColor];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

    NSLog(@"Type: %i",drawType);

    switch (drawType) {
            case 0:
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10, 100);
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 300);
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
                CGContextStrokePath(context);
                break;
            case 1:
                CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context,CGRectMake(10, 100, 300,440));
                CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
                break;
            case 2:
                CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(10, 100,300,300));
                CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }

}


-(void)drawNow:(NSInteger)type {
    drawType = type;
    NSLog(@"Draw Now! %i",drawType);

    //[self setNeedsDisplay]; // Not working...
    //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; // Not Working
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DrawView.h"

DrawView *mydraw;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *drawTypeSW;

- (IBAction)drawNow:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize drawTypeSW;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mydraw = [[DrawView alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setDrawTypeSW:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)drawNow:(id)sender {
    [mydraw drawNow:drawTypeSW.selectedSegmentIndex];
}
@end
```

When I open the app a line is draw but when I try to draw something else using the button `Draw Now` it doesn't work, nothing happens and `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` is not called. Why? What am I missing?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Further Edit, final resolution**: The DrawView being created in `viewDidLoad` wasn't being added as a subview to the ViewController. Adding the following line should make it appear correctly (in addition to other fixes below):

```
[self.view addSubview:mydraw];
```

**Edit**: An extension to my answer (which still stands, but I think isn't the core of the problem anymore). You're declaring `myDraw` *outside* of the interface (and doing something similar in DrawView's header file). Instead of

```
DrawView *mydraw;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
//snip
@end
```

try:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
DrawView *mydraw;
}
//snip
@end
```

**Original answer:**
The variable `myDraw` hasn't been properly initialised - `UIView`s need to be initialised using either initWithFrame (for programmatic creation) or initWithCoder (when in a nib or storyboard). Using init to create it means it has a frame location/size of 0 (and other UIView functionality may be not initalised properly), which in turn means it won't draw properly.

Try either a) creating a UIView in your nib/storyboard, turning it into a DrawView, and making the `drawView` field in your ViewController definition an outlet for that view. Or b) Remove it from your nib, create your DrawView using initWithFrame, specifying a location and size on the screen for it.

Comment: I changed the `myDraw` to inside the interface and it's still not working... What do you mean by "UIViews need to be initialised using either initWithFrame". What do I need inside my `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` at DrawView.h? Thank you ;)

Comment: Nothing, if you don't need any custom initialisation. I was referring to where you instantiate it in ViewController.m: `mydraw = [[DrawView alloc] init];` should be something more along the lines of `myDraw = [[DrawView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 200, 200)];` (for example; the parameters to CGRectMake determine where the view appears). Given you said it does draw a line at first though, I suspect this isn't the problem - though it is still an issue that should be resolved.

Comment: I've made that change ;) the problem remains.

Comment: Given that there's only two possibles I can think of you need to double-check. Use log statements and/or breakpoints to make sure a) `- (IBAction)drawNow:(id)sender` is actually getting called, and b) that myDraw is definitely not nil when that method is called (though it shouldn't be). All I can assume at this point is that the Draw Now button isn't correctly linked up to `drawNow:` on the ViewController.

Comment: Using an `NSLog();` I can't tell you that `-(void)drawNow:(NSInteger)type` at `DrawView.m` is called and it runs but seems like the `[self setNeedsDisplay];` has no effect and is not calling `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` again.

Comment: Okay, rebuilt your project on my system, got a couple of questions: 1. Is the pale green area in your screenshot intended to be the DrawView?  If so, is it specified in Interface Builder to be a DrawView rather than UIView? 2. If it is in IB and supposed to be the view, change your declaration of `mydraw` in ViewController.h to be an IBOutlet property named mydraw, and link up the view in IB to it. 3. If it isn't, then a) What is it? b) to make the view you create in viewDidLoad appear, you must add the line `[self.view addSubview:mydraw];`.

Comment: 1. Yes and is specified as `DrawView` ; 2. I've done that change, still no progress; 3. That draws a black view with the line that actually updates as I click `Draw Now`. Thank you! Screenshot: http://cdn.iklive.net/tcb13/2012/drawstuff.PNG

Comment: My guess is you actually had two views: one was the one created in IB, the other the one you made in `viewDidLoad`. The one in IB wasn't hooked up properly (and I can only assume still isn't, as 2. should've worked otherwise), so it drew it's initial state but didn't respond to inputs. The one in `viewDidLoad` wasn't added as a subview, so never drew at all. Since it's that latter one we've got updating atm, you should be able to delete the one in IB and reposition the other using the params to `CGRectMake` as appropriate.

Comment: Last comments says it all, easier that way. Thank you for all your time and help. :)